# Load MultiFrame Icons

Tags: delphi, icons, delphi-2010

Does anyone know of a class that can read multiframe icons?  Searching the internet has not produced any information.

I tried using IconTools 2.0 by Alan Peter Stotz, which loads the icons into a list correctly but the bit-depth for 8-bit and 4-bit icons return as 0.  The bitdepth for 32 and 24-bit icon frames is returned correctly, however.

The icon itself appears correct when viewing... just the bitdepth is wrong for the bits mentioned.

**EDIT #2**
Baised on the comment by TLama here is some untested code:

```
function NumberOfIcons ( AFileName: string ): integer;
var
  iNumberOfIcons: Integer;
begin

  iNumberOfIcons := ExtractIcon ( hInstance, PChar ( AFilename ), UINT ( -1 ) );
  Result := iNumberOfIcons;

end;

function ExtractAnIcon ( AFilename: string; AIndex: integer ): TBitmap;
var
  icoHandle: HIcon;
  iBitmap: TBitmap;
  iIcon: TIcon;
  iNumberOfIcons, i: Integer;
begin

  Result := nil;

  iBitmap := TBitMap.Create;

  iIcon := TIcon.Create;
  try

    // Get the number of Icons
    iNumberOfIcons := ExtractIcon ( hInstance, PChar ( AFilename ), UINT ( -1 ) );

    // Extract the icon frame
    icoHandle := ExtractIcon ( hInstance, PChar ( AFileName ), AIndex );
    iIcon.Handle := icoHandle;
    iBitmap.Width := iIcon.Width;
    iBitmap.Height := iIcon.Height;
    // Draw the icon on your bitmap
    DrawIcon ( iBitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, iIcon.Handle );    
    Result := iBitmap;

  finally
    iIcon.Free;
  end;

end;

function PixelFormatToBitDepth ( APixelFormat: TPixelFormat ): integer;
// Convert TPixelFormat to integer
begin

  Result := -1;
  case APixelFormat of
    pf32Bit:
      Result := 32;
    pf24bit:
      Result := 24;
    pf8bit:
      Result := 8;
    pf4Bit:
      Result := 4;
    pf1bit:
      Result := 1;
  end;

end;
```

Am I on the right track?  In my testing I now get 1 icon but the NumberOfIcons function is returning 1?

**EDIT#3**
According to the help file "If the file is an .ICO file, the return value of ExtractIcon is 1."  So what method can be used to get the number of icons in the ico file?

Comment: Are you planning to edit them further or are you just wanting to use them in a program? If the latter then it is easier to link them as resources and use the resource APIs to get the right version of the icon.

Comment: @David... I am trying to use them in an ImageEditor that loads bitmaps, so once I get the icon I need to convert it to a bitmap, then get its width and height and bitdepth.  I am attempting to use ExtractIcon to do this baised on TLamas comment.  I added the untested code as an edit.

Comment: @Bill, ImageEditor shipped with Delphi ? If so, then try to forget on it. I have a good experience e.g. with IcoFX (there's also portable version of it) which allows you to export icons into several formats (*.bmp including). But you don't need to use only bitmaps in resource files, you can use any file type, you just have to compile the resource files by your own.

Comment: I think posting untested (and probably unworking a priori) code is really a wrong move. Better post code you really have problem with.

Comment: @TLama.  No It is a bitmap editor http://www.omuller.com/.  The code I posted is getting the iconframe now but I can not get the number of icons in the .ico file.  I do not need resource files just .ico files.  Is there something wrong with using ExtractIcon to return the number of frames in the icon?

Comment: @user539484.  The code is being tested now and the code I posted is the code I am having a problem with... NumberOfIcons always returns 1 and not the number of icons in the file.

Comment: @Bill, it happens because *If the file is an .ICO file, the return value is 1.* Check out the docs

Comment: Well, I'd read the code in Graphics.pas that reads .ico files. That's pretty comprehensive. And the primary documentation source from MS is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx

Comment: According to the help file "If the file is an .ICO file, the return value of ExtractIcon is 1."  So what method can be used to get the number of icons in the ico file?

Comment: @TLama, it is *reference*, not a *scriptures*, do not seek hidden sense there :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, well, code in Graphics tries to mimic an API and select a **single** image of the best size. I think OP should better off proceed directly to that format specification.

Comment: @user539484 Yes, I know what that code does. But it gives some useful ideas how to implement what is needed. Hence the link to the actual docs. Reading the Delphi code in Graphics.pas may make it easier to read the abstract MS docs, and vice versa. That's certainly been my experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small code example:

```
uses ShellApi;

type
  TICONDIRENTRY = packed record
    bWidth: Byte;          // Width, in pixels, of the image
    bHeight: Byte;         // Height, in pixels, of the image
    bColorCount: Byte;     // Number of colors in image (0 if >=8bpp)
    bReserved: Byte;       // Reserved ( must be 0)
    wPlanes: Word;         // Color Planes
    wBitCount: Word;       // Bits per pixel
    dwBytesInRes: DWORD;   // How many bytes in this resource?
    dwImageOffset: DWORD;  // Where in the file is this image?
  end;

  TICONDIR = packed record
    idReserved: Word; // Reserved (must be 0)
    idType: Word;     // Resource Type (1 for icons)
    idCount: Word;    // How many images?
    idEntries: array [0..255] of TICONDIRENTRY;
  end;
  PICONDIR=^TICONDIR;

function GetIconsCount(const FileName: string): Word;
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  IconDir: PICONDIR;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if ExtractIcon(hInstance, PChar(FileName), UINT(-1)) <> 0 then
  try
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Stream.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      IconDir := Stream.Memory;
      if IconDir.idType = 1 then
        Result := IconDir.idCount;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  except
    // do not raise exceptions
  end;
end;

function ExtractIcons(const FileName: string; IconList: TList): Boolean;
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  NewIconStream: TMemoryStream;
  IconDir: PICONDIR;
  NewIconDir: PICONDIR;
  Icon: TIcon;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  if ExtractIcon(hInstance, PChar(FileName), UINT(-1)) <> 0 then
  try
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Stream.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      IconDir := Stream.Memory;
      for I := 0 to IconDir.idCount-1 do
      begin
        NewIconStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          NewIconStream.Size := SizeOf(Word) * 3 + SizeOf(TICONDIRENTRY);
          NewIconStream.Position:= SizeOf(Word) * 3 + SizeOf(TICONDIRENTRY);

          NewIconDir := NewIconStream.memory;
          NewIconDir.idCount := 1;
          NewIconDir.idType := IconDir.idType;
          NewIconDir.idReserved := IconDir.idReserved;
          NewIconDir.idEntries[0] := IconDir.idEntries[I];
          NewIconDir.idEntries[0].dwImageOffset := NewIconStream.Size;

          Stream.Position := IconDir.idEntries[I].dwImageOffset;
          NewIconStream.CopyFrom(Stream, IconDir.idEntries[I].dwBytesInRes);
          NewIconStream.Position := 0;
          Icon := TIcon.Create;
          Icon.LoadFromStream(NewIconStream);
          IconList.Add(Icon);
        finally
          NewIconStream.Free;
        end;
        IconList.Add(Icon);
      end;
      Result := True;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  except
    // do not raise exceptions
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: string;
  Icon: TIcon;
  List: TList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  FileName := 'c:\myicon.ico';
  List := TList.Create;
  try
    if ExtractIcons(FileName, List) then
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Icon := TIcon(List.Items[I]);
      DrawIcon(Form1.Canvas.Handle, 10, I * 40, Icon.Handle);
      Icon.Free;
    end;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Kobik... thank-you... I seem to be having some sucess with http://www.tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/kicon.html as well.

Comment: @Bill, BTW KIcon uses the same method above i.e `TKIcon.LoadFromStream`->`FIconCount := IH.idCount;`.

Comment: Heh, interesting, never knew what it is possible to proceed with ExctractIcon in the described case.